# Http client on android (sending a string to a server and getting a string answer)

Tags: android, http, post, get

I'm implementing a simple android http client, which will send an image to a server via POST, and get a string answer. I figured that image will be sent as a String too, in a `Base64` format.

Now, on StackOverflow I found lots of examples of using `HttpClient`, however, it is now marked as deprecated. So what should I use and how? External libraries are allowed. A code sample on how to send a `Base64` string to a server and get a string answer is extremely welcome!
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon); 
    new UploadHandler().execute(icon); // pass your bitmap here....

private static class UploadHandler extends AsyncTask<Bitmap,Void,String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Bitmap... bitmaps) {
        try{
            return uploadImageToServer(bitmaps[0]);
        }catch (Exception ex){
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        // Update UI here
        // Find post request response here and your stuff ...
        Log.i("JSON","onPostExecute: " +  s);

    }


    public static byte[] getEncodedPNGImage(Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        //this will convert image to byte[]
        byte[] byteArrayImage = baos.toByteArray();
        // this will convert byte[] to string
        baos.close();
        return byteArrayImage;
    }


    private String uploadImageToServer(Bitmap myBitmap){
        try {
            URL url = new URL("your image upload endpoint");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            String data = "{ \"image\": \"" + getEncodedPNGImage(myBitmap) + "\" }";

            Log.i("JSON", data);
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            os.writeBytes(data);

            os.flush();
            os.close();

            Log.i("JSON","STATUS: " + String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
            final String msg = conn.getResponseMessage();
            Log.i("JSON","MSG: " +  msg);


            conn.disconnect();
            return msg;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("JSON", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what about the response?